# How can I repost a post after I mistakenly removed it?

Tags: facebook

How can I repost or get an post mistakenly removed?

Comment: As far as I know, there's no "Recycle Bin" or "Trash" in Facebook. Unless you've got it cached in your browser you're probably out of luck.

Answer (score 3):

Type it in again, and click Post.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately there is no function available to recover a deleted post. Once a status update has been deleted, it can't be recovered at the moment.

As *@Al E.* has [commented](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/87904/how-can-i-repost-a-post-after-i-mistakenly-removed-it#comment75199_87904), there's no "Recycle Bin" or "Trash" in Facebook.

See the [Help Centre](https://www.facebook.com/help/356107851084108#What-happens-to-content-%28posts,-pictures,-etc%29-that-I-delete-from-Facebook) page about this.